# print_r($json) return blank page

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

I use a json code, when I am run my program not show anything. just bank page please help me to solved it
This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Percobaan</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <input type="text" id="scrap" name="scrap" placeholder="Input Hashtag ex: malang">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['scrap'])) {
        $hashtag=$_POST['scrap'];
        $html=file_get_contents("https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%23".$hashtag."&src=typeahead_click");
        $json=json_decode($html,true);
        print_r($json);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you should be using `CURL`

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi - _"should"_ is a strong word. If you're just doing a simple GET request (and have `allow_url_fopen` set to true), using `file_get_contents()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Does it actually enter the if-statement? Have you checked your error log? A good idea is also to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103427/what-are-php-allow-url-fopen-security-risk

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi - Did you read the comments on those two (unexcepted) answers? And since you should _always_ sanitize user data correctly before using it, that won't really be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The response is not JSON data, it is just an HTML content, you can only parse the JSON content through the valid JSON data.